# Force route placeholder to be always treated as query string parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following route on an action within an controller that has a route prefix:

```
[Route("{page?}", Name = "MyRoute")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int page = 1)
```

`IUrlHelper.RouteUrl` gives me an url ending with `/1` for `MyRoute` and `Page = 1` as route values. This isn't wrong but I'd like `page` to always be a query string parameter.

How can I do this in MVC 6? If possible I want to avoid parsing the result of `RouteUrl` method and setting the page as query string parameter myself. [Routing docs](https://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/controllers/routing.html) are still empty. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26520870/764754) answer suggests using `[FromUri]`attribute although it sounds like this serves a different purpose and it seems not be available in MVC 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work by not having the parameter `{page?}` in the route.

Initially I had `[Route("Bar/{page?}", Name = "BarRoute")]` which was giving me `/Bar/1`

I got it to work with an Action set up like:

```
    [Route("Bar", Name = "BarRoute")]
    public IActionResult Foo(string page)
    {
        ViewBag.PN = page;
        return View("Index");
    }
```

This razor mark up:

```
<li>@Html.RouteLink("Click here!", "BarRoute", new { page = 1 })</li>
```

Generated:

```
<li><a href="/Bar?page=1">Click here!</a></li>
```

And in a Controller:

```
ViewBag.Thing = this.Url.RouteUrl("BarRoute", new { page = 1 });
```

Gave:

```
/Bar?page=1
```

---

Additionally, `[Route("", Name = "BarRoute")]` generated `http://localhost:62405/?page=1`